# Xgboost and LSTM support in Apache Ignite ML and DL

Tags: java, machine-learning, deep-learning, ignite, gridgain

In our machine learning based system we have used Xgboost and LSTM algorithms. I want to use Apache Ignite In-Memory Grid-based machine learning libraries([Apache Ignite Machine Learning Grid](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/machine-learning)) to optimize this system's performance. Does Apache Ignite ML and DL libraries have the support of Xgboost and LSTM algorithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your data location and your goals. Does your data is already stored in Apache Ignite? Do you use Apache Ignite in your ecosystem?

Regarding **XGBoost**, Apache Ignite doesn't provide trainers for boosted trees so far, but you can use *imported* XGBoost models. You can find an example of such importer [here](https://github.com/dmitrievanthony/xgboost-model-importer). If you trains your model outside of the Ignite and then use the model in Ignite to process data this approach will be good enough for you.

Regarding **LSTM**, Apache Ignite ML currently supports only MLP neural networks, so you can't train your model inside Apache Ignite. Even so you still can train the model outside of the Apache Ignite and then import prepared model.